# Arrangements and Selections with Repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of the letters in PEPPERMILL are there with
a) The M appearing to the left of all the vowels?
b) The first P appearing before the first L?

For part a, I have know that the total arrangements of PEPPERMILL is 10!/(3!2!2!). And from this I want to subtract the cases where the M appears to the right of all the vowels. I just don't know how to calculate those. I have no idea how to approach part b.

Answer (score 3):

(a) You don’t want to remove just the arrangements with the M to the right of **all** of the vowels: you want to remove the arrangements with the M to the right of **at least one** of the vowels. But it’s easier in this case to count the arrangements that you **do** want, i.e., those with the M to the left of all of the vowels. Treat the letters M,E,E,I as one group and the letters L,L,P,P,P,R as another. There are $\binom{10}4$ ways to choose which four of the ten positions are to be filled with M or a vowel. Once you’ve chosen those, you know that the M must occupy the first of the four, and the E,E, and I can then be arranged in $\frac{3!}{2!1!}=3$ distinguishable ways in the remaining three positions. Finally, the other six letters can be arranged in $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}$ distinguishable ways in their positions, so the final number of arrangements is ... ?

(b) This problem can be solved in similar fashion. There are $\binom{10}5$ ways to choose the positions to be occupied by the letters L and P. To get the first P before the first L, you **must** put a P in the first of these five slots. Now how many distinguishable ways are there to distribute the remaining two P’s and the two L’s amongst the other four slots set aside for them? And how many distinguishable ways are there to distribute the other five letters amongst the remaining five slots?

Answer (score 1):

> Answer: (A) $ 3\times \frac{10!}{4!3!2!} $ ; (B) ${4 \choose 2} \times \frac{10!}{5!2!}$

(A)

Let the set of all such valid sequences be $\Delta$, we are interested in finding $|\Delta|$.

The idea is to regard M and vowels as the same letter, say $Z$. Then we can replace $Z$ by $M$, $E$ and $I$ to get a sequence in $\Delta$, like this:

> $PZPPZRZZLL \Rightarrow \{PMPPIREELL, PMPPERIILL, PMPPEREILL\}$

There are $\frac{10!}{4!3!2!}$ ways to arrange $PZPPZRZZLL$. For each of them, we can substitute $...Z...Z...Z...Z...$'s in place by $MIEE$ , $MEII$ and $MEEI$ sequentially, to produce three distinct valid sequences in $\Delta$. Hence the answer is $3 \times \frac{10!}{4!3!2!}$.

(B) Use the same idea, regard $P$ and $L$ as the same letter first.

Comment: do you have an easier approach to this question? I don't quite follow your logic.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Regardless of the other letters, the ordering of $\{M,E,E,I\}$ within the total arrangement is completely arbitrary. So exactly 1/4 of them have the $M$ before all the vowels: the answer is ${1\over 4}\cdot {10!\over 3! 2! 2!}=  37800$.

(b) The fraction  of arrangements with the first $P$ before the first $L$ is $3/5$: the answer is ${3\over 5}\cdot {10!\over 3! 2! 2!}= 90720$.